# we need some helps with join in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have table (commandeclients, bonlivraisons, factureclientatvas) and I want to get all the bonlivraisons connected to commandeclients which is connected to factureclientatvas.

How can I make this work? Is it correct?

```
$bl = DB::table('bonlivraisons')
        ->join('commandeclients', 'bonlivraisons.commande_id', '=', 'commandeclients.id')
        ->join('factureclientatvas','commandeclients.id','=', 'commandeclients.id')
        ->join('factureclientatvas','commandeclients.id','=', 'bonlivraisons.commande_id')
        ->where('factureclientatvas.id','=',$id)
        ->select('bonlivraisons.reference')
        ->get();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please, read and then edit your question

Answer (score 0):

You are joining `factureclientatvas` twice.

In the first you are trying to join it where

```
'commandeclients.id', '=', 'commandeclients.id'
```

Then, you are trying to join it where

```
'commandeclients.id', '=', 'bonlivraisons.commande_id'
```

--

Both seem incorrect as it should be something like

```
->join('factureclientatvas','factureclientatvas.id','=', 'commandeclients.factureclientatvas_id')
```

or something like

```
->join('factureclientatvas','factureclientatvas.id','=', 'bonlivraisons.factureclientatvas_id')
```

--

Joining of the `factureclientatvas` is dependant on how you have your tables are structured and the logic of your application.